# How to open Xcode from terminal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I noticed my current bash file has `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/library/bin`
 which i put there to set up terminal access to mamp. I've been trying to compile `-a MyApp a.xcodeproj` & `open a.xcodeproj` but I'm not sure which one to use and neither works. I also added this to the bash file after suggestion `$ alias xcode="open -a Xcode"` It still doesn't work. I need a path/terminal expert to help me configure a way to run Xcode from the terminal because I'm trying to use cocoa pods.

Comment: open /Users/Apple/Desktop/MyApp.xcodeproj if terminal says it doesn't exist, it means it doesn't exist, check your desktop path, and I guess your are entering a wrong path, normally xcode projects are in a folder so your path must be open /Users/Apple/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj

Comment: `open` with the `.xcodeproj` should work

Comment: Specifically, put `alias xcode="open -a Xcode"` into your ~/.bash_profile ... Is that specific enough for you?

Comment: I recently [released a custom script](https://github.com/jasonmccreary/oxc) I wrote to open Xcode from the command line I named `oxc`. Future readers may find it helpful.

Answer (score 238):

xed does this and ships with xcode.  Run

```
xed .
```

`man xed` for more info.

Comment: That's what I use. But for frameworks - it doesn't open the *.xcodeproj file for some reason. Any way around that?

Comment: Thanks for this. Still works as of 3021. This is similar to `code .` of VSCode. Awesome!

Comment: for opening with multiple versions of Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73948657/4995828

Comment: @GlennPosadas good to know its future proof 

Answer (score 52):

If `open .xcodeproj` doesn't work, then you can use the following to force Xcode to open via terminal.

**Step 1.**

Open Terminal. I am assuming you know how to do this, because your question was how to open Xcode in the terminal.

**Step 2.**

Type the following line in terminal. This will open your `.bash_profile` with `vim` (a terminal text editor). The `~/` means that it will open it in your home directory. So your current location doesn't matter.

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

**Step 3.**

When using `vim` you will need to go into insert mode, which basically means you can start typing into the file. To do this you will just need to hit the <kbd>i</kbd> key.

```
i      // <- this will get you into insert mode
```

**Step 4.**

Then type the following on it's own line in `.bash_profile`. This tells bash, to set an alias up, the alias's name will be `xcode`, and the alias value will be `open -a Xcode`. Make sure you do not have any spaces on the left or right of the equals sign (`=`).

```
alias xcode="open -a Xcode"
```

**Step 5.**

Since we went into insert mode by using the <kbd>i</kbd> key, you need to hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit insert mode. then hit the <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> key to escape, write, and quit.

```
ESC    // <- this will exit insert mode
:wq    // <- writes and quit the file
```

**Step 6.**

This will need to reload your bash profile in bash, after making changes to it. The `.` will basically run your `.bash_profile` again.

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

**Step 7.**

Using the alias.

Make sure you are in the same directory as the `name.xcodeproj`, check this by using `ls`. If you see it do the following:

```
xcode name.xcodeproj
```

obviously you want to replace `name` with the file name

Comment: If you were following the steps, when you do step 2, you will be inside your `.bash_profile`

Comment: I'm taking this as yes

Comment: my current bash file reads: export        alias xcode="open -a Xcode

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i just opened my bash file via `open -a TextEdit.app .bash_profile` and pasted `alias xcode="open -a Xcode"` under what was already in there.  `open a.xcodeproj ` still doesn't work

Comment: @Program1 make sure you do step 6, or else your `.bash_profile` will never be reloaded.

Comment: @Program1 also be careful when using TextEdit as it try's to use rich texts, which isn't suitable for bash. You asked for step by step, and you aren't even following it, step by step.

Comment: Also `open -a TextEdit.app .bash_profile` will create a `.bash_profile` in the directory you are currently in, you should follow the steps that use `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Also, just using this:        Step2->In terminal (zsh): $vi ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 9):

Very simple:

Get into the directory of the project; you can tell if your in the proper directory by typing "ls" (short for 'list') into terminal and if you see the .xcodeproj suffix on your project name then you're in the right spot.

> open projectname.xcodeproj

The project will then open into Xcode

Shortcut: on a macbook you can many times type just the first letter or two of your projectname and if you hit 'tab' it will autocomplete it.  So you could type the above code like this...

> open pr[tab]
>   then you'd see...
>   open projectname
>   then you'd type...
>   open projectname.xc[tab]
>   and it would finish that too to end up like this...
>   open projectname.xcodeproj

Comment: More MOUSEY solution but easier to remember? If you're in the proper directory already, you can also try typing... open .  (type: open [spacebar] period [return] ) and this will bring up a Finder menu open to your directory.  Then just double-click your project file which ends in ".xcodeproj" and it will open Xcode and your project.

Comment: I had a duh moment when I read this. Just open it!

Answer (score 8):

Old thread, but I just recently researched if there's a way to open Xcode from the terminal myself, and was not satisfied when discovering the overly verbose `$ open -a Xcode projname.xcodeproj` command. You could alias half the command like Arian Faurtosh's answer, but if you're going to edit a bash script, a function can serve you much better.

My solution:

```
# Function to open Xcode projects from the command line, call with $ xcode
function xcode {

  proj=$(ls -d *.xcodeproj/ 2>/dev/null)

  if [ -n "$proj" ]; then
    # Omit -beta if you're not using beta version
    open -a Xcode-beta "$proj"
  else
    echo "No Xcode project detected."
  fi

}
```

Save above code to whatever file your shell sources each session. Now you can use `$ xcode` and it will launch Xcode as long as your current directory contains a .xcodeproj dir.

Comment: May need to run `open -a /Applications/Xcode.app "$proj"` if `Xcode-beta` does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

You are in wrong directory. Consider 'a' folder on desktop that contains a.xcodeproj and other files. *Navigate to 'a' directory* in terminal.

```
MACBOOK-Users: macbook$ cd Users/macbook/Desktop/a
```

Now, `macbook$ open a.xcodeproj` on terminal. 
This opens 'a' project in Xcode.

Comment: the app is on my desktop and i did cd desktop

Comment: @Program1 : Now, cd/<FolderName-Containing-XcodeProject>

Comment: very cool. please see this next question (the second part) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577946/what-is-the-path-to-this-project

Answer (score 3):

## Open specific Xcode

1. Choose specific Xcode version you want to open with.
2. Copy the Xcode developer directory filepath, e.g. `/Applications/Xcode-13.2.1.app/`.
3. Run `xcode-select -s` with the filepath. e.g. `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-13.2.1.app`
4. Navigate to folder of Xcode project using `cd`, or alternatively copy it directly to step 5.
5. `xed .` / `open *.xcodeproj`

Et voila! With this approach we can open projects using multiple versions of Xcode from the command line.

<sub>I prefer using `xed` rather than `open` because the tool is the "Xcode Editor" tool and has been specifically designed to open Xcode projects. It will choose the xcworkspace over xcodeproj automatically and open package projects too. :D</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think your current directory is wrong. Move to the directory which contains MyApp.xcodeproj file.

Comment: type "ls", and see if the file exists on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your terminal:

```
echo "alias xca='cd ~/path/to/project/directory && xed .'" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Open a new terminal and run:

```
xca
```

Your terminal will take you to your project directory (*useful for committing code changes*)
and it will open your project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).