# Launching Xcode as a separate process

Tags: xcode, cmake

I have an xcode project that is generated using CMake.

It depends heavily on environment variables some of which are absolute paths.
If I launch several environments and generate the same project with different configs, the first env vars take over because Xcode reuses the same process.

Is it possible to launch Xcode in its own process so that each Xcode instance will have its own unique environment?

OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.5
Xcode: v10.3.1

Comment: I think you try opening xcode from terminal and each time you open xcode, you can define different parameters in command line, refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639914/how-to-run-xcode-from-terminal 
Since, you haven't shared the OS version, so can't help you with exact command.

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576238/how-to-open-xcode-from-terminal - use xed . seems neat

Comment: @AkanshGulati Thanks, but this won't do the trick, it simply reuses the same process, what I need is for it to launch in a new process.

Comment: @JGFMK thanks, but this doesn't do the trick either, xed re-uses the same process.

Comment: Even if you use separate tabs in the Terminal? Would have to check. You are correct. Two xed's. One Xcode..